# TIP122 constant current problem

Tags: constant-current

I am driving a TIP122 via the DAC of an ESP32 which only reaches 3.16V

The solenoid is rated at 2.4A at 12V.

Irrespective of what I put the supply voltage up to I can't obtain more than about 2.1 amperes into the solenoid. I would have expected 12V on the solenoid, 2.4V on sensing resistor and 2 to 3V on Vce so say 16V on supply.

Could someone shed light on this, please?

[image]

---

Thank you for your answers.. I get the same response if I totally remove R2 as mentioned in my second post. At 2.1Amps I get 2.6V Vce..  If you look at these curves from an earlier thread I would have thought Vce should be < 1 V

[image]

---

- Removed R2
  Altered the supply voltage down
  Vs = 15V     Vce  = 2.52   Vb = 13.4
  Vs = 14 V    Vce  = 2.50    Vb = 12.43

as mentioned above I would have thought Vce should be <1 V

Comment: Also, same response with or without the 10K base resistor

Comment: Why don't you make some measurements? What is the output voltage of the LM358, the emitter voltage of the Darlington and the voltage across the sense resistor? What is the warm resistance of the coil? The 100nF cap is asking for trouble.

Comment: @RodMcM - Hi, Your "answers" weren't answers to your original question, and therefore should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box. Instead they have now been added to the question as edits i.e. updates. Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, [edit] the question to add new information. This is one of the ways that Stack Exchange is different to typical forums. See the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Comment: @RodMcM - If you want to alert a specific site member who has already written an answer (or a comment) that you have updated the question with new information, then write a *comment* below their answer (or their comment) using `@their-username` at the start of the comment. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more about writing comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solenoid coil must be 12V/2.4A or 5 ohms, so you have 6 ohms connected to your emitter.  At 2.1 amps, this makes your emitter voltage 12.6 volts.  Add the TIP122's worst case 2.5-volt VBE(on), and your base voltage would be 12.6+2.5 or 15.1 volts.  LM358 output swing is 1.5 below Vdd (18-1.5 volts or 16.5 volts), so you have a worst-case voltage drop of 16.5-15.1 or 1.4 volts across the 10K base resistor (R2).  This means your base current would be only 0.14 milliamps, and the TIP122 has a worst-case current gain of 1000, which would provide only 0.14 amps of collector current.

These are all worst-case values, and you are obviously not doing this poorly, but you get the idea.  Start by reducing R2.  I agree with @Sphero Pefhany that C1 is probably not a good idea and may cause instability.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree, R2's voltage drop is the culprit here. I question the need for it at all, unless it's participating in some frequency compensation. Drop R2 altogether, or make it 100s of ohms, not 10000, if you're worried about the LM358's output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on John's answer - if you move the solenoid to the collector side of the TIP122 and re-run his analysis, you will see that there is much greater headroom for the opamp to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the solenoid between the supply and collector. Vce now goes below 1V and I get the current I want.. Thanks for this.. I will still try to work through why in the other configuration VCE was above 2V